# NullPointerException onCreate - android spinner

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I'm having trouble with a spinner on my application.

The spinner is supposed to pass the selected Item to an SQlite DB and save data.

But so far everytime I press my register button it throws the `javaNullPointerException` error.

This is my class:

```
public class RegisterMember extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener{
DbAdapter dbAdapter;
EditText txtName;
EditText txtPassword;
EditText txtPasswordConf;
EditText txtEmail;
EditText txtEmailConf;
EditText txtSchool;
Button btnJoin;
//Button btnRegister;

private String[] state= {"USB","Stanford","Harvard","UCV","USM","Tor vergata", "La Sapienza"};
Spinner spinner_school;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_members_register);
    System.out.println(state.length);
    spinner_school = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_school);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter_state = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, state);
    adapter_state
    .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner_school.setAdapter(adapter_state);
    spinner_school.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    //btnRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_reg);

    dbAdapter = new DbAdapter(this);
    dbAdapter.open();

    btnJoin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(txtName.getWindowToken(), 0);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(txtPassword.getWindowToken(), 0);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(txtPasswordConf.getWindowToken(), 0);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(txtEmail.getWindowToken(), 0);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(txtEmailConf.getWindowToken(), 0);
            //imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(txtSchool.getWindowToken(), 0);
            //imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(spinner_school.getWindowToken(), 0);
            try {

                String name = txtName.getText().toString();
                String password = txtPassword.getText().toString();
                String passwordconf = txtPasswordConf.getText().toString();
                String email = txtEmail.getText().toString();
                String emailconf = txtEmailConf.getText().toString();
                //String school = txtSchool.getText().toString();
                String school = spinner_school.getSelectedItem().toString();
                long i = dbAdapter.register(name, password, email, school);
                if(i != -1)
                    Toast.makeText(RegisterMember.this, "You have successfully registered",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                else {
                    if(!passwordconf.equals(password))
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Password Does Not Matches", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    if(!emailconf.equals(email))
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Email Does Not Matches", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                }

            } catch (SQLException e) {
                Toast.makeText(RegisterMember.this, "Some problem occurred",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }

        }
    });
}
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                           long id) {
    spinner_school.setSelection(position);
}
@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

The spinner on my layout:

```
<TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow10"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/spinner_school"
            android:spinnerMode="dropdown" />

    </TableRow>
```

And the stack trace, it starts on method `btnJoin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()`

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.shairlook/com.kkoci.shairlook.RegisterMember}: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2295)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:150)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1280)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:175)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5279)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.kkoci.shairlook.RegisterMember.onCreate(RegisterMember.java:57)
```

Any ideas? I've looked through examples but I still can't figure out this

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT on duplicate**

No, duplicate does not solve my question because SQLite is involved here, that a is a simple method issue, thanks.

**SECOND EDIT**

This is how `btnJoin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {` method looks like right now, same error:

```
btnJoin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(txtName.getWindowToken(), 0);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(txtPassword.getWindowToken(), 0);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(txtPasswordConf.getWindowToken(), 0);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(txtEmail.getWindowToken(), 0);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(txtEmailConf.getWindowToken(), 0);
            //imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(txtSchool.getWindowToken(), 0);
            //imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(spinner_school.getWindowToken(), 0);
            try {

                txtName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_user);
                String name = txtName.getText().toString();
                txtPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_pw_reg);
                String password = txtPassword.getText().toString();
                txtPasswordConf = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_pw_conf);
                String passwordconf = txtPasswordConf.getText().toString();
                txtEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_email_reg);
                String email = txtEmail.getText().toString();
                txtEmailConf = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_email_conf);
                String emailconf = txtEmailConf.getText().toString();
                //String school = txtSchool.getText().toString();
                spinner_school = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_school);
                String school = spinner_school.getSelectedItem().toString();
                long i = dbAdapter.register(name, password, email, school);
                if(i != -1)
                    Toast.makeText(RegisterMember.this, "You have successfully registered",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                else {
                    if(!passwordconf.equals(password))
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Password Does Not Matches", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    if(!emailconf.equals(email))
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Email Does Not Matches", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                }

            } catch (SQLException e) {
                Toast.makeText(RegisterMember.this, "Some problem occurred",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't assigned any value to `btnJoin`. This is causing the exception.

---

**Edit 1 - How to fix the problem**

To fix this problem, and also other problems that would happen if you click the button, add the following lines to your onCreate() method after `setContentView(R.layout.activity_members_register)`:

```
txtName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.register_member_name);
txtPassword = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.register_member_password);
txtPasswordConf = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.register_member_password_confirm);
txtEmail = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.register_member_email);
txtEmailConf = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.register_member_email_confirm);
txtSchool = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.register_member_school);
btnJoin = (Button)findViewById(R.id.register_member_button_join);
```

As long as you have something like this on your layout file:

```
...
<EditText android:id="@+id/register_member_name" ... />
...
<EditText android:id="@+id/register_member_password" ... />
...
<EditText android:id="@+id/register_member_password_confirm" ... />
...
<EditText android:id="@+id/register_member_email" ... />
...
<EditText android:id="@+id/register_member_email_confirm" ... />
...
<EditText android:id="@+id/register_member_school" ... />
...
<Button android:id="@+id/register_member_button_join" ... />
...
```

Where `register_member_name`, `register_member_password`, `register_member_password_confirm`, `register_member_email`, `register_member_email_confirm`, `register_member_school` and `register_member_button_join` are the widgets ids. You don't have to use exactly these names. As long as you are using the same values in both the layout file and java implementation, everything is going to be fine.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are forgetting to "find" and inflate the widgets from your view. Because of that, when you call 
    txtName.getText().toString();
it throws nullPointerException because your txtName is still null.

To solve this, you need to inflate all your widgets in you code before trying to access them. So right after you call setContentView(), you do:

```
txtName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.the_id_of_the_widget)
```

for all of your widgets.

EDIT: You are still getting the same error because you still haven't inflated the Button.

add :

```
 btnJoin = (Button) findViewById(...)
```

before you call the setOnClickListener.

Answer (score 1):

you should try this inside your onClick method

```
 spinner_school = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_school);
  String school = spinner_school.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

and Please put findviewByid in all the widget

Comment: Tried it, no success :(

Comment: there should be null in your code that why the error came out

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80956/discussion-between-jameshwart-lopez-and-neove).

Answer (score 1):

your problem is right there:

```
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.kkoci.shairlook.RegisterMember.onCreate(RegisterMember.java:57)
```

Look at line 57 of your RegisterMember.java, you are trying to access some variable thats not being initialized. Can't see line numbers so I can't help you any further...which is your line 57?